# What strategy should you have to use Firebase/Firestore from a vue.js application located in a page of a Drupal site?

Tags: vue.js, firebase-authentication, drupal

I would like users already connected to my Drupal site to be able to use my application directly without having to register or log in a second time to use Firebase/Firestore.

Is this possible and how?

If this is not possible, should we keep the standard Drupal registration to control access to the application page and use a second registration for the application?

Thank you for your suggestions and your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the information about your user's Drupal sign-in available to Firebase (e.g. in your Firestore security rules), you will have to tell Firebase about the user. This is a two-step process:

1. [Mint a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) based on their Drupal sign-in on a trusted environment, such a server you control, or a serverless system like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run.
2. [Sign in to Firebase with that custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth#authenticate-with-firebase) on the client.

Once you complete these steps, the information you put into the token will be available in the `request.auth` variable in your Firestore security rules.